# phpStorm10 - How to write "[" bracket

Tags: phpstorm, shortcut

I am using Phpstorm10 since 4 hours but I feel like stupid... I don't know why I can't write bracket "[]"

I am on azerty keyboard so it should be "alt gr + ("

Thanks !

EDIT Solution :
 delete the line with the setting "USE_NON_ENGLISH_KEYBOARD" from the file "C:\Users[username]\WebIde100\config\options\keyboard.xml" and it worked just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try a workaround from [this comment](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-91975#comment=27-384169)

Comment: Thank you for the link but with the version 10, there is not file "bin/idea.properties" :/

Comment: it is there, I swear:) BTW, were you prompted to "Enable smart keyboard internalization for PhpStorm"? may be same issue as https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-142462